# Choosing an alternate resistor or capacitor in a circuit

Tags: resistors

My question may look stupid but it's great trick in case of repairing in a battlefield.

When a resistor or capacitor gets damaged in a circuit and if the required value is not available then what should be the strategy.Choosing a high value or a low value,which would be the best solution.

Comment: Entirely depends on the application and that components purpose in the circuit.

Comment: This seems to be too abstract to resolve to a recommendation, and so isn't a good fit for this site. Please read the [help] to understand how to ask good questions that get good answers. As your question is currently written, I think Funkyguy has given you a near-definitive answer. Other people might silently vote to close unless you improve the question; I'm usually willing to "cut people some slack" in the hope that they will improve the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You choose the correct value or find a way to get it. That is the correct strategy.

The circuit, when designed, was chosen to have certain specs and so component values were chosen to accomplish that.

Some components can be generic somewhat arbitrary in range, but others are critical to is operation. How do you know ? You need the schematic or you were one of the designers who designed it so you know what you need.

Sometimes the value can be arbitrary in a range, but its the component properties that matter. Sometimes capacitors are added not so much for their capacitance, but for their ESR.

So the correct answer, is you find a way to get the right component.